# import csv file into mysql without workbench

Tags: mysql

I am try to import csv file into mysql in command prompt without workbench.
But it shows error like ERROR.
what is the best way to import csv file without workbench.

what is best way to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
    INFILE 'yourPATH/table.csv'
    INTO TABLE `table`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

Use this to find your path:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to turn off the option '--secure-file-priv':

In my.cnf file, add the following line under [mysqld]:

```bash
secure_file_priv=
```

Generally my.cnf file is at /etc/mysql/my.cnf, or you can search it by:

```bash
sudo find /* -name my.cnf
```